# Assembly runtime version v2.0 in Visual Studio 2010 .net 4 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I downloaded a library(SquishIt) I want to use in a Console Application. I am working in Visual Studio 2010 so the Target framework is set to ".Net Framework 4" in the properties of the application. This causes the following error in my code:

> The type or namespace name 'SquishIt' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

When I switch the Target framework to 3.5 the problem goes away.

Could anybody explain why this happens?

Comment: Did I ask something weird or didn't I give enough information?

Comment: Seems to be an obscure problem; I've had no problems at all referencing .NET 2.0 assemblies from 4.0 projects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ErikHeemskerk. I'll try and ask the developer that made the library.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, while .NET 3.0/3.5 added a lot of new functionality, it did not introduce any changes to the CLR, meaning that it was backwardly compatible with assemblies targeting the 2.0 framework.  .NET 4 introduces some CLR changes, so no backward compatibility.

Comment: Wrong.  .Net 4.0 is backwards compatible.